# how to read data delimited by space and save it to arrays,and then write it other order in new text file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

psedo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    double beta[250];
    char Batob[250], eq[250];
    ifstream myfile("iter1/HMMemit0.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            if (!(iss >> Batob[i] >> eq[i] >> beta[i])){ //it store only B in Batob[i], but i want to save B00 in Batob[i], = in eq[i], and 0.524671 in beta[250]
                break;
            }
                i++;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

my data stored in HMMemint0 like this

```
B00 = 0.524671 
B01 = 0.001000 
B02 = 0.001000 
B10 = 0.001097 
B11 = 0.001000 
B12 = 0.001000
```

i want to read a line and save each term in each variable like B00 saved in name[i], and 0.001000 in beta[i].
and then, write it in this 0.524671(B00's value) 0.001097(B10's value) order like this

```
0.524671 0.001097  
0.001000 0.001000 
0.001000 0.001000
```

How can i do it? please help me.

Comment: You are having char[] for B00s which is a string list.

Comment: Since both `Batob` and `eq` are character arrays, your reading will will read `'B'` into `Batob[i]` and the first digit into `eq[i]`. They both need to be strings instead.

Comment: Also, you might want to read about [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) which is a data-structure for key-value pairs, which is what you seem to have in the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a char array for "BXX"s, whereas you want strings. Basically, you want a string array, or even vector. The problem is that only 'B' will be read from "BXX" into your first parameter.

This code works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    double beta[250];
    string Batob[250];
    char eq[250];
    ifstream myfile("iter1/HMMemit0.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            iss >> Batob[i] >> eq[i] >> beta[i];
            i++;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: I was just fixing your code with the least impact, but of course if you start using proper C++ containers like `vector`, the `i` variable could be easily eliminated as the elements and the index would be maintained automatically.

Also, since you are using the equal sign ('=') all the time for the char array, it is a bit needless waste of memory, which could be severe in case of a big file.

I would say, using an associate container in the future would be even more productive for your `BXX` keys and their corresponding `values` on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

`Batob` is an array of characters, so `Batob[i]` is a single character. That's why your program reads only one character. If you want to read 250 *strings of characters* you need to make room for them. The simplest (not necessarily the best, however) method is to declare an array like `char Batob[250][100]` – this would be an array of 250 arrays, 100 characters each. Then `Batob[i]` is a 100-chars array and you can input a string with `iss >> Batob[i]`.

Comment: string looks more suitable to me than two hard-coded array sizes with 2d arrays. That makes the code quite hard coded, although in this special case one could assume size 3 based on the input, so even then 100 is probably an overkill. :)